# wget an remote website index directory

Tags: file-transfer, wget

Is it possible to wget an entire index/parent directory with wget? Because I am trying to transfer images to a VPS of mine from my old shared host.

When I say an index/parent directory, I meant like this:

[image]

So basically I want wget to go through each file and download it until all have been downloaded.

Cheers.

Comment: just playing devils advocate here...you don't have ftp access to your old shared host?

Comment: I agree with @iain, if its your vps can't you just tar/zip or transfer using ftp/sftp/scp?

Comment: I do have ftp access, but I don't know how to do FTP from vps to old host.

Comment: You can use your desktop as the middleman- Download everything from old server to your desktop, FTP to new server, upload.

Comment: Not with my 100kb/s speeds, no. That would take me forever lol.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense :) Best approach is prob to sftp from the new server to the old (if you have shell access to that command on your new VPS) heres a good sftp command line explanation: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did mention there is ftp access, 
wget actually supports ftp out of the box:

```
wget -r -l0 --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=pass ftp://yourdomain.com/dir/*
```

Answer (score 2):

the -r (recursive) wget switch should work, -l X specifies how deep to traverse (5 levels max):

```
wget -r -l 1 http://domain.com/directory/
```

source: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download

Comment: Damn! I knew there was an easier way. Mine's more creative. :) Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

Assuing you have no shell or FTP access nor any control panel, and that this is a legitimate request, you might want to have a look at spidering software - I've found [pavuk](http://www.pavuk.org/) useful for this in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if wget supports this or not, but you could use a bash script to accomplish this fairly easily.

Step 1. Copy and paste all of the text from the "index of /i" into a file called "files" or something else that makes sense on the new host.

Step 2. On your new machine use the following command to do a search & replace to create the wget commands for each file you need to download.

```
cat files | sed "s/^/wget http:\/\/yoursite.com\/path\//"
```

This reads the file named "files" and then pipes it to sed which inserts "wget http://yoursite.com/path/file1.png"

For example I ran it on a file on my local computer. The "files" file contains just the .png files like the following:

```
blah.png
blah1.png
blah2.png
```

and the output looks like the following after running the command posted above.

```
wget http://yoursite.com/path/blah.png
wget http://yoursite.com/path/blah1.png
wget http://yoursite.com/path/blah2.png
```

At that point, you just copy and paste the all the wgets that are generated in terminal or from command line it it will download each file.